# Method that returns data from service

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a method that returns value from the database using Angular. But this code is not working.

In typescript:

```
get getData(){
    return this.accountService.accountSelect().subscribe((res) =>{
      return res;
    });
}
```

In html:

```
{{ getData }}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you share more code? Like `accountSelect()`

Comment: Is this possible? data = this.getData(); console.log(this.data) ?

Comment: yes but you can use a local variable to store the data and use that variable

Comment: Or else provide the all related code will help

Answer (score 4):

Because that's not how it works.

Try this instead.

```js
get getData(){
    return this.accountService.accountSelect();
}
```

```html
{{ getData | async }}
```